# GitHub CLI: command not found

Tags: git, github-cli

I have `git` and `gh`, both installed through scoop. I set up the git authentication using

```
gh auth login
gh auth setup-git
```

However, when trying to `git fetch`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\[user]\scoop\apps\gh\current\bin\gh.exe auth git-credential get: C:Users[user]scoopappsghcurrentbingh.exe: command not found
C:\Users\[user]\scoop\apps\gh\current\bin\gh.exe auth git-credential store: C:Users[user]scoopappsghcurrentbingh.exe: command not found
```

This is my `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --wait
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/[user]/Python/Coney_Colabs
    recentrepo = "C:/Users/[user]/C#/azrielCode"
[user]
    email = [user]@gmail.com
    name = [user]
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = 
    helper = !C:\\Users\\[user]\\scoop\\apps\\gh\\current\\bin\\gh.exe auth git-credential
[credential "https://gist.github.com"]
    helper = 
    helper = !C:\\Users\\[user]\\scoop\\apps\\gh\\current\\bin\\gh.exe auth git-credential
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
```

Comment: The Git code that reads `.git/config` interpolates ``\\`` to one ``\``. You've set the credential helper to `!...`, so Git passes the line **after** interpolation to the shell. The shell therefore sees `C:\Users\you\scoop\apps\gh\current\bin\gh.exe auth...`. The *shell* interpolates each backslash as a backslash escape sequence, but `\U` doesn't mean anything special to it becomes `C:U`, `\you` becomes `you`, `\apps` becomes `apps`, and so on. To get one backslash through the *shell* you must provide the *shell* **two** backslashes, which requires *four* backslashes in the `.git/config` line.

Comment: (This is why most people use forward slashes if and when they work.)

Comment: Meanwhile, the empty `helper =` lines are not doing you any good, so you can delete them if you like.

Comment: I don't fully understand, what backslashes do I need to change to forward slashes?

Comment: Here, *all* of them, but only if it works. If it does work you never need to double any of them: that is, instead of `C:\\\\Users\\\\you\\\\apps...` you'd just need `C:/Users/you/apps...`.

Answer (score 3):

You should see:

```
helper = !\"C:\\Users\\[user]\\scoop\\apps\\gh\\current\\bin\\gh.exe\" auth git-credential
```

But an alternative approach if to make sure your `%PATH%` includes `C:\Users\[user]\scoop\apps\gh\current\bin`, and simply use `gh.exe auth git-credential` in your config. No more escaped backslash.